# Pegar imagem do AWS e anexar ao email?

Tags: java, amazon-aws

É possível 'upar' uma imagem no aws, e depois anexá-la a um email?
Eu pensei em duas coisas: Se há um jeito de recuperar o arquivo diretamente do servidor aws ( como se fosse meu pc,por exemplo, onde eu procuro a imagem e anexo),

ou com o sistema já online, fazer o download dessa imagem dinâmicamente, salvar no projeto, anexar ao email, depois excluir.

Dá pra fazer isso?

Comment: Ate onde conheço da AWS-S3 vc pode fazer o download dessa img sim passando o link dela, mas para isso o arquivo tem q estar com aceso publico. vc pode tentar anexar a img em base64, porem não é todos servidores de email que permitem usar base64, melhor é anexar por link

quanto ao sistema on-line também é possível ^^

Comment: Como eu posso fazer isso? (o anexo é para o gmail)

Comment: Quando subir o aquivo use o link de acesso a ele, lembre se o acesso ao arquivo tem q ser publico, e use como se fosse uma img qualquer "linkda" a um e-mail por URL.

para fazer o download da img da uma olhada na documentação da AWS S3, é bem completa um pouco bagunçada, mas completa

Comment: Sim, é relativamente simples. Coloca seu código que ajudamos.